# Windows 10 not using the available memory

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have 24GB of RAM installed which has always been plenty.  Recently my machine has become slower and freezes a lot.

I have noticed in the Process Explorer that the system commit and physical memory remained only use a fraction of what’s available.  I can run VS 2022, SQL Server, and execute a query returning 8,000,000 records and memory use is static.

[image: Memory - Low]

Initially, I thought the hardware was at fault so I reseated the ram and swapped the sticks around.  I even reinstalled windows (not a clean reinstall).

Then I discovered a single exception to the rule.  Running a PowerShell script that included the following lines

```
for ($cnt = 1; $cnt -le $cnt_max; $cnt += 1) {
    $mem += $data * $mem_block
    Write-Output ('{0,-10}{1}' -f $cnt, (($cnt * $mem_block)/1000MB))
    sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Produces the following output:

[image: Memory - Full]

What gives?  How can I get the rest of my software to use the available memory?

The machine is almost 10 years old - which is like 200 in people-years.  Can it have dementia?

**Edit**
So, allow me to clarify the question. The first graph would be what I see during normal operations.  I can then start SQL Server, launch VS 2022, and any number of other programs, and the memory use does not change but the computer becomes glitchy (e.g. freezes periodically). It is as if all the software are competing for the same 8GB of memory.

Comment: Software will not use more memory than it needs. (If we forget about faulty behavior.) If you feel your software isn't make effective use of available memory, use different software.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Why do you want software running on your system to use memory it does not need.  If you fill memory with 500 MB chunks.  Your script will use that memory. 19 GB out of 26 GB being available means that, 19 GB is immediately available for use by any application that requires it.  You are only using 25% of your page file.

Comment: Recently my machine has become slower and freezes a lot. ........   Have you looked in Reliability History to see what is happening?  Have you updated all Drivers?  Is Windows fully up to date?

Comment: Why don't you post Task Manager's view on it. Performance tab. Select Memory. The balance between Available and Cached will tell us if you are short of memory.

Comment: Programs like SQL server tend to manage their own memory using special knowledge of their memory usage. It uses functions like `VirtualAlloc` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc. Normal programs use stack and heap memory, often indirectly via a computer language.